# Two RFID readers yield different IDs (not byte order difference)

Tags: tags, number-formatting, uniqueidentifier, rfid, serial-number

I have a GEZE door reader for RFID tags. The web app shows for one RFID tag the number "0552717541244". When I read the same tag with a USB reader connected to my computer, it shows "0219281982".

The values in hex are `d11fa3e` and `80b0885f7c`. So it does not seem to be the difference in byte order discussed in other similar questions.

Is there a way of finding out the *longer* number when only the *shorter* one is known?

How come one single tag can have two different identifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at only a single value pair makes it impossible to verify if there actually is some systematic translation scheme between the two values. However, looking at the binary representation of the two values gives the following:

```
decimal               binary
0552717541244  ->  1000 0000  1011 0000  1000 1000  0101 1111  0111 1100
   0219281982  ->             0000 1101  0001 0001  1111 1010  0011 1110
```

So it looks as if the web app reverses the bit order of each byte when compared to the reading of the USB reader and adds an additional byte 0x80 as the MSB:

```
decimal               binary
0552717541244  ->  1000 0000  1011 0000  1000 1000  0101 1111  0111 1100
                    (added)   -------->  -------->  -------->  -------->
                              <--------  <--------  <--------  <--------
   0219281982  ->             0000 1101  0001 0001  1111 1010  0011 1110
```

Comment: Great! I actually had expected something more difficult, like some hashing. Instead of finding it out the way you did, I thought someone might have known the algorithm from experience with the GEZE system.